# ¿se puede enviar solicitud ajax PUT con un archivo file?

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, update, javascript-metodo

Estoy intentando enviar un formulario que contiene un un archivo `file`, sin embargo es para realizar una solicitud de ajax con `type:put` para la cual se debe utilizar `.serialize()`, segun estuve investigando el `formData` solo funciona para `type:post`.

Como podria enviar una solicitud ajax `type:put` que pueda incluir un archivo.

HTML:

```
<form id="formulario" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input  type="file" id="fotoSeguridad" name="fotoSeguridad"   accept="image/*">         
</form>
```

JQ: tengo dinamizado el tema del tipo `put` o `post` y otros elementos con variables.

```
  /* registro del formulario */
  $('#formulario').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formulario = $('#formulario')[0];
    var data;
    if (tipo=="POST") {
      data = new FormData(formulario);
      data.append("file", fotoSeguridad.files[0]);
      EnvioFormulario(data,urlFormulario,token,tipo);  
    } else {
      data = $("#formulario").serialize();
      EnvioFormulario(data,urlFormulario,token,tipo);
    }                              
  });
```

AJAX:

```
    function EnvioFormulario(datos,urlFormulario,token,tipo) {
      $.ajax({
          type: tipo,
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token}, 
          url: urlFormulario,
          data: datos,
          contentType: false,
          datatType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          processData:false,
          success: function(data)            
          {   
              console.log("guardo exitosamente");  
          },
          error: function (data)
          {  
              console.log("Error al guardar"); 
          }     
      });           
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede, debes usar como metodo POST, y añadir al formData un attributo _method que debe ser PUT, de este modo la peticion sera POST, pero laravel podra determinar que debe ir sobre tu ruta PUT.

```
data.append("_method", "PUT");
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, me dio resultado